# Update column with data from another table's column

Tags: mysql, sql-update, inner-join

Let's say I have two tables in a MySQL database. I would like to update the data from a column in the source table to a column in the target table.

> Source table is called 'Computers_F1' Source column is called 'Family'.
>
> Target table is called 'Advice' Target column is called 'Fase1'

I want to put all the rows from 'Family' into 'Fase1'. But this without it adding new rows. I want all the information to be updated in the existing rows.

Hope you guys can help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this if you have a column id to match both

```
UPDATE Advice AS a
SET Fase1 = (SELECT Family FROM Computers_F1 AS c WHERE a.id = c.id)
```

And then rename the column Fase1

```
ALTER TABLE Active CHANGE `Fase1` `Family` VARCHAR(255)
```

(replacing VARCHAR(255) with the right format of your column)

Comment: Thanks for your help. However, the problem is the column names should preserve their name because this is important for the rest of the script.

Comment: You want the column Fase1 in the table Advice to be rename Family ?

Comment: Well, maybe i can put 'Family' column from 'Computers_F1' into 'Advice' and then rename that column to 'Fase1'. Could you show me how to do that?

Comment: 'a' and 'c' are just alias for the tables Advive and Computers_F1 (defined using 'AS'). It's just an easy way to proceed when you write queries with complex tables name. 
The WHERE clause 'a.id = c.id' is equal to 'Advice.id = Computers_F1.id'

Comment: Thanks a lot for your clear explanation. It has helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I know 2 ways:

```
UPDATE Advice, Computers_F1
SET Advice.Fase1 = Computers_F1.Family 
WHERE Advice.Id = Computers_F1.Id;
```

OR

```
UPDATE Advice
INNER JOIN Computers_F1
ON Advice.Id = Computers_F1.Id
SET Advice.Fase1 = Computers_F1.Family;
```

Hope this helps...

**UPDATE**

Correct examples, with foreign keys:

```
UPDATE Advice, Computers_F1
SET Advice.Fase1 = Computers_F1.Family 
WHERE Advice.Computers_F1_Id = Computers_F1.Id;
```

OR

```
UPDATE Advice, Computers_F1
SET Advice.Fase1 = Computers_F1.Family 
WHERE Advice.Id = Computers_F1.Advice_Id;
```

OR

```
UPDATE Advice
INNER JOIN Computers_F1
ON Advice.Computers_F1_Id = Computers_F1.Id
SET Advice.Fase1 = Computers_F1.Family;
```

OR

```
UPDATE Advice
INNER JOIN Computers_F1
ON Advice.Id = Computers_F1.Advice_Id
SET Advice.Fase1 = Computers_F1.Family;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Actually I'm a total newbie when it comes to PHP. What should I fill in after the WHERE statement? Advice.ID... <- What should this ID become?

Comment: This ID is the column that "connects" the two tables (Advice and Computers_F1). There must be a foreign key in one of these two tables referencing other. See the update above.